# 424 Run-time error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA - been learning it since last week and I wanted to review my findings and I know this is the silliest thing you're going to come across.

I keep getting this error:

> Run-time error '424':
>   Object required

Here is the code and the error message:

```
Sub Button1_Open()
    Button1.OnClick MsgBox("Tester")
End Sub
```

Any help? I know this is going to be really silly. I've tried adding `Set` but that didn't work either.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that code?

Comment: Just so when you click the Button that has this assigned macro, the message box appears and just says tester.

Comment: You use VBA. Not VB.NET, not VB Script and not BASIC. This is VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change method name from **'Open'** to **'Click'** as follow:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    MsgBox("Tester")
End Sub
```